# Insert into database java oop

Tags: windows, textpad

Hello i have student project
How can I make a library file project,Black screen (cmd),using oop Include
(insert Delete update display)
without
import java.x.*;
import java.awt.*;
i use textpad

Comment: so you mean without any ide, you need develop a java oop console application, right?

Comment: no clue what you mean.

Comment: i want to make a library with books and information in Java oop , I do not know from where start

Comment: start from open an ide, create one project, writing main classes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.